Flutter Camera Plugin Crashes After App Resumes from Background
I am encountering an issue with the Flutter camera plugin where my app crashes after it resumes from the background. The error occurs specifically when trying to start the camera stream.
I initialize the camera in the initState method of my StatefulWidget.
On app lifecycle changes, I pause and resume the camera feed.
I use CameraController to start the live feed and process camera images.
didChangeAppLifecycleState to handle pausing and resuming of the camera.
didPopNext to resume the camera feed when returning to the screen.
Package
 camera: ^0.10.6
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  _initializeCamera();
}

Future<void> _initializeCamera() async {
  await _viewModel.initialize(widget.initialCameraLensDirection, context);
  if (!_viewModel.isCameraInitialized) {
    await _viewModel.initialize(widget.initialCameraLensDirection, context);
  }
}

@override
void dispose() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  _viewModel.stopLiveFeed(); // Ensure live feed is stopped properly
  super.dispose();
  _viewModel.customPaint = null;
}

@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
    _viewModel.pauseLiveFeed();
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    _viewModel.resumeLiveFeed();
  }
}

@override
void didPopNext() {
  super.didPopNext();
  if (!_viewModel.isDisposed) {
    _viewModel.resumeLiveFeed();
  }
}

/Camera  (10294): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
I/Camera  (10294): CameraCaptureSession onClosed
W/System  (10294): A resource failed to call release. 
I/Camera  (10294): open | onError
I/Camera  (10294): close
W/CameraManagerGlobal(10294): ignore the torch status update of camera: 21
W/CameraManagerGlobal(10294): ignore the torch status update of camera: 22
W/CameraManagerGlobal(10294): ignore the torch status update of camera: 23
I/BufferQueueProducer(10294): [ImageReader-1280x720f100m1-10294-0](id:283600000001,api:4,p:719,c:10294) disconnect(): api=4
W/CameraManagerGlobal(10294): ignore the torch status update of camera: 61
I/BufferQueueProducer(10294): [SurfaceTexture-0-10294-0](id:283600000000,api:4,p:719,c:10294) disconnect(): api=4
E/CameraManagerGlobal(10294): Camera 61 is not available. Ignore physical camera status change
I/BufferQueueConsumer(10294): [ImageReader-1280x720f100m1-10294-0](id:283600000001,api:0,p:-1,c:10294) disconnect()
I/BufferQueueConsumer(10294): [ImageReader-1280x720f23m1-10294-1](id:283600000002,api:0,p:-1,c:10294) disconnect()
I/Camera  (10294): open | onClosed
2
V/PhoneWindow(10294): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@6bb8edc, this = DecorView@d8b0be5[MainActivity]
I/mali_config(10294): @get_buffer_dataspace_setting: update dataspace (0x10010000 -> 0x08020000)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Surface android.media.ImageReader.getSurface()' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.startCapture(Camera.java:615)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.startPreviewWithImageStream(Camera.java:1210)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at io.flutter.plugins.camera.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:259)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7864)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android(10294):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
E/flutter (10294): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Surface android.media.ImageReader.getSurface()' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Surface android.media.ImageReader.getSurface()' on a null object reference
E/flutter (10294):  at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.startCapture(Camera.java:615)
E/flutter (10294):  at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.startPreviewWithImageStream(Camera.java:1210)
E/flutter (10294):  at io.flutter.plugins.camera.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:259)
E/flutter (10294):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
E/flutter (10294):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
E/flutter (10294):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/flutter (10294):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (10294):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/flutter (10294):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/flutter (10294):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
E/flutter (10294):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7864)
E/flutter (10294):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (10294):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
E/flutter (10294):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
E/flutter (10294): )
E/flutter (10294): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
E/flutter (10294): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
E/flutter (10294): <asynchronous suspension>

SOLUTION
Update the camera package to latest version.
But I have to implement yuv420toNV21 conversion.
